# Android: Can't decide on multiple if's or nested switch statements

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm creating an android app which will call a method which parses the selected item of multiple spinner objects. I'm very new to Java, and I'm not sure which statement is best to use in terms of program flow in this instance. Should I just use multiple If statements? Such as:

```
If(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0 && spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2 && spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4)
/* do some stuff
```

Or would it be better to use switch statements?

```
switch(spinner1.getSelectedItem())
case 1:
    switch(spinner2.getSelectedItem())
    case 1:
        switch(spinner3.getSelectedItem())
        case 1:
        /* do something
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do here is evaluate the selected item of each spinner object, then create a new Activity based on that evaluation. However the initial activity consists of several spinner boxes, each with several options, so I'm not sure the best way to go about designing the control statements. Using an if statement for every single possible combination of selected items seems a bit unwieldy. Additionally, I'm not sure which option will actually make the code work the way I intend it to.

Comment: For a readability discussion, we'd need to know a little more about the do something part. Could these nested switches be broken out into separate methods so they're not so painful to refactor/read later on.

Comment: Perhaps. I'm trying to troll for ideas, since I'm a novice here. I want the app to create a new activity based upon the values of all 4 spinners. All in all there is only like 15-20ish options, but I don't understand the best way to go about evaluating all those options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a switch statement will be more effective, because you can send multiple results into the same section of code (sounds like that might be necessary for your application) like this

```
switch(value) {
case 0:
case 1:
    //Do THIS
    break;
case 2:
    //Do THAT
    break;
default:
    //Doesn't match any
}
```

If value evaluates to either 0 or 1, the first section will be executed and you only had to write the operation code once.  As for specifics (now I'm just getting creative), you could shift the three spinner values into a single integer and switch on the result.  If you write the case statements in hexadecimal, it will be more readable as to the state of each.

```
int result = 0;
result += (byte)(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition() << 16);
result += (byte)(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition() << 8);
result += (byte)(spinner3.getSelectedItemPosition());

switch(result) {
case 0x000000: //All spinners 0
case 0x010201: //S1 = 1, S2 = 2, S3 = 1
    //Do something
    break;
case 0x010101: //S1 = 1, S2 = 1, S3 = 1
    //Do something else
    break;
default:
    //Everything else (good if most of your options go to the same Activity)
}
```

Hope that Helps!

Possible drawback to this example: Only 256 options allowed for each spinner ;)

Comment: Thanks! I was actually mulling something similar to this in my head just now. I was gonna add all the values together and switch the result, but couldn't quite get around the fact that the result would be equal to 1 if the first index of ANY spinner was selected. What you've suggested makes perfect sense.

Comment: Switch statements usually need at least half a dozen different cases before they're more effective than a cascaded if/else if at least in C#. 
Also the C# compiler changes switches to if/else ifs so I'd assume the other way is also allowed and it won't matter from a performance perspective because the compiler will change it anyhow to whatever it wants ;)

Answer (score 2):

Choose readability above anything else, because in performance or program flow there are no big differences.

Comment: Well I intend to go with what's most readable. The problem I'm facing is, I'm not sure which option here will actually make the code work the way I intend it to :)

Comment: I think the switch statement would be better, it would be a hell to maintain or understund so much nested ifs x).

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you may not want either. This could be a situation where you want to change the eventListener for the spinner's change event. Rather than handle all of the logic in one big method.

Answer (score 0):

I think that almost depends on how many choices the user has, if they are too many, the switch may be the best choice.

However, you cans also arrange them in categories, and each one in different modules, in something like a progression page, every time the user has selected some of one categories, show the next one and so on

Answer (score 0):

So each of four spinners has x states? Or do you want to capture just one specific state and have some 'else' branch for the others?

In the end this will all become very lengthy, so that cascaded switch statements may be easier to read.

Depending on the input data you could also do something else:

If you have 4 spinners, then multiply the position of the first by 1000, of the 2nd by 100 , the third by 10 and the last by 1. Then add the numbers together and have fund with a few thousand `case:` statements ):-)

Answer (score 0):

From a purely performance standpoint, switch statements are faster. The initial expression passed into the switch is evaluated once and then checked against the case values. For an if statement the both the left and right hand side of the if check is evaluated each time. So using if statements would be a bit slower.